# i cannot make a window with python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

i want to create a GUI window with tkinter in python. it was no problems but since i changed my laptop's windows ( and re-installed python 3.11 ) it cannot make a window.
so when i import the tkinter library , it knows the library ( no problems till here )
but then , when i write :

```
import tkinter
win = Tk()
```

it says :

```
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

i'd like to mention again that in the past when my windows was 11 and my python was 3.10 , it worked fine but now it doesn't.

edit for @Tranbi
now it works fine but gives another error on Tk :

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 
'Tk' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: `win = tkinter.Tk()`

Comment: but how the hell it worked like i said in my past windows?

Comment: I doubt that. You might have used `from tkinter import *` which btw isn't good practice. I personnaly prefer `import tkinter as tk` then call `tk.Tk()`

Comment: Have you just named your file `tkinter.py` ?

Comment: no - it's test.py